# ES6 typescript class create object of itself inside

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, object, ecmascript-6

I have created a class and inside that class i want to create an array that consist of object of itself. In normal javascript if achieve it as follow

```
class Person{
     constructor(name){
         this.name=name;
      }
     setList(list){
        let listItem=[];
        for(const lt of list){
           listItem.push(new this.constructor(lt));
        }
       return listItem;
     }
}
```

In typescript

```
class Person{
     name:string;
     constructor(name){
         this.name=name;
      }
     setList=(list:Array<string>)=>{
        let listItem=[];
        for(const lt of list){
           listItem.push(new this.constructor(lt));
        }
       return listItem;
     }
}
```

i get error above code `this.constructor(lt)` as follow

```
This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'Function' has no construct signatures.ts(2351)
```

Comment: Why do you make `setList` a class field in TS?

Comment: so i can convert array string to array object of person, and as it is a object it can holds other many property like name and other many methods that can do different work on those property. and this method is there exactly, because it will be easy to remember that  the class itself can generate its own list. I hope, I am able to answer your question

Comment: I'm not questioning why the method exists but why you make it a class field. You can keep it as a prototype method, just like in the non-TS version `setList(list: string[]) { ... }`. Otherwise every object gets its own copy of the function which seems unnecessary.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I am new to ES and typescript and did not realize the impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TypeScript, the type of `this.constructor` in a class is always `Function`; however, TypeScript allows you to make a reference to a class within its declaration, so, simply replacing the `this.constructor` with the name of the class, (`Person`), itself will work fine. See below:

```
class Person {
  name: string;
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  setList = (list: Array<string>) => {
    let listItem = [];
    for (const lt of list) {
      listItem.push(new Person(lt));
    }
    return listItem;
  };
}
```

If you absolutely need to go the  `this.constructor` way, you can strongly type the constructor like so:

```
class Person {
  name: string;
  ["constructor"]: typeof Person;

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  setList = (list: Array<string>) => {
    let listItem = [];
    for (const lt of list) {
      listItem.push(new this.constructor(lt));
    }
    return listItem;
  };
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes i need to use this.constructor  any way because this person class can be extends by other classes. and in this case using `["constructor"]`without typeof Person; helped me. Thank you